# Which is the best python framework for developing Facebook application as on now

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are developing Facebook applications in python, my query is which is the best python framework for developing Facebook application as on now. which will run easily with GAE as well as with Django...

Thank you very much.

** edit **

I think my query was misunderstood.. We are looking for a best python based facebook framework which can easily be used in django applications as well as GAE applications..

- It would be good if you can provide reasons for recommending particular framework...

I DONT WANT TO RUN DJANGO ON GAE.

Comment: I may have completely misunderstood things, but are GAE and Django not two completely different Python frameworks themselves?

Comment: @neil django can run on appengine. http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel

Comment: i think the question is a non-question. to access facebook you do so through their api's , there's python code that wraps those api's(google for it), if you are using python you can call python code like pythons facebook api wrappers for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's remove the facebook buzzword from the equation. If you need/want to leverage google's infrastructure, you use appengine. There are projects for django that allow you to access appengine services at a higher level of abstraction such as the datastore, blobstore etc...

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel

I wouldn't call it the best solution but if the Django style of development is what you are comfortable with, it's a good option. I personally prefer using google's model api for the orm and using something else for routing requests to views. bfg/pyramid is a good option if your routing fits the notion of an object graph, and you can get instance level security fairly easy if you do if thats something you need.

conclusion: it all depends on what you need to do. :)